# How do I get Average field length and Document length in Lucene?

Tags: lucene

I am trying to implement BM25f scoring system on Lucene. I need to make a few minor changes to the original implementation given [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-2091?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3aall-tabpanel#issue-tabs) for my needs, I got lost at the part where he gets Average Field Length and document length... Could someone guide me as to how or where I get it from?

Comment: I've browsed this issue a while ago, I guess this implementation calculates average field and document length outside Lucene (while submitting documents for indexing for example). As far as I know Lucene doesn't have this feature (average field and document length).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get field length from `TermVector` instances associated with documents' fields, but that will increase your index size. This is probably the way to go unless you cannot afford a larger index. Of course you will still need to calculate the average yourself, and store it elsewhere (or perhaps in a special document with a well-known external id that you just update when the statistics change).

If you can store the data outside of the index, one thing you can do is count the tokens when documents are tokenized, and store the counts for averaging. If your document collection is static, just dump the values for each field into a file & process after indexing. If the index needs to get updated with additions only, you can store the number of documents and the average length per field, and recompute the average. If documents are going to be removed, and you need an accurate count, you will need to re-parse the document being removed to know how many terms each field contained, or get the length from the `TermVector` if you are using that.

Comment: lets say I don't like the increase in index size, then ?

Comment: If you don't store term vectors, you will have to count the number of terms in each field at indexing time, and store those counts or averages somewhere. A "special" document is one possibility. Another possibility is to use some database or key-value store to store index statistics. Remember to update them if you add or delete documents, though. Of course if your documents are all similar in length, then being off a little bit won't hurt the BM25 stats.